# how to get the time when exiting a textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, textfield

I have a form with some textfields for entering some words. I would like to save the times when the user has finished entering his/her input in each textfield. These time info should be posted eventually to the server when the form is submitted. Any help?

Comment: You should have a timer which starts as soon as the page is fully loaded and then when the user clicks the submit/send button the timer should stop and send it to your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `keyup`, store the current time in a hidden input.

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/hL8YB/

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name_input">
<input type="hidden" name="name_time" id="name_time_input" size="100">

<script>
$('#name_input').keyup(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    $('#name_time_input').val(now.toString());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a textbox with the time and ID it "timer" for this example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer = null;
    var interval = 1000;
    var value = 0;
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        value = value + 1;
        $("#timer").val(value);
    }, interval);

$('#submitbutton').click(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
    var k = $('#timer').val();
    $('.time').html(k); //or alert(k); or send it to your server using post method.
});
});
```

This isn't tested but to give you a direction to take to accomplish what you are looking to do

You can also use the `.load();` function instead of the `.ready();` function.

Comment: you can change the .click() to .keyup() as Trevor mentioned below for each text box instead of the final time.